Tailwind product overview component with alpine.js is not working properly
The problem is that the image selector can't select an image.
I get lots of error messages in my console saying Alpine (function name) is not a function and Alpine expression is not defined.
This alpine code does work:
    <h1 x-data="{ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }" x-text="message"></h1>

I've tried the following:

Updating/downloading tailwindcss and alpine.js

    npx tailwindcss init
    npm install alpinejs


Changing the scripts at the end of the body (footer.php).

<!--<?php //echo site_url('/node_modules/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css'); ?><!--" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!--<?php //echo site_url('/node_modules/alpinejs/dist/alpine.min.js'); ?><!--" defer>-->


Installing the following plugins.

plugins: [
      // ...
      require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
      require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    ],

The code snippet:
<div class="flex flex-col-reverse" x-data="Components.tabs()" @tab-click.window="onTabClick"
     @tab-keydown.window="onTabKeydown">
    <!-- Image selector -->
    <div class="mx-auto mt-6 hidden w-full max-w-2xl sm:block lg:max-w-none">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-6" aria-orientation="horizontal" role="tablist">
            <button id="tabs-1-tab-1"
                    class="relative flex h-24 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-white text-sm font-medium uppercase text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:ring-offset-4"
                    x-data="Components.tab(0)" aria-controls="tabs-1-panel-1" role="tab" x-init="init()"
                    @click="onClick" @keydown="onKeydown" @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" :tabindex="selected ? 0 : -1"
                    :aria-selected="selected ? 'true' : 'false'" type="button" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">
                <span class="sr-only">Angled view</span>
                <span class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                    <img src="#" alt="" class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center">
                </span>
                <span class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-0 rounded-md ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-indigo-500"
                      aria-hidden="true" x-state:on="Selected" x-state:off="Not Selected"
                      :class="{ 'ring-indigo-500': selected, 'ring-transparent': !(selected) }"></span>
            </button>
            <button id="tabs-1-tab-2"
                    class="relative flex h-24 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-white text-sm font-medium uppercase text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:ring-offset-4"
                    x-data="Components.tab(0)" aria-controls="tabs-1-panel-2" role="tab" x-init="init()"
                    @click="onClick" @keydown="onKeydown" @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" :tabindex="selected ? 0 : -1"
                    :aria-selected="selected ? 'true' : 'false'" type="button" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Front view</span>
                <span class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                    <img src="#" alt="" class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center">
                </span>
                <span class="ring-transparent pointer-events-none absolute inset-0 rounded-md ring-2 ring-offset-2"
                      aria-hidden="true" x-state:on="Selected" x-state:off="Not Selected"
                      :class="{ 'ring-indigo-500': selected, 'ring-transparent': !(selected) }"></span>
            </button>
            <button id="tabs-1-tab-3"
                    class="relative flex h-24 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-white text-sm font-medium uppercase text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:ring-offset-4"
                    x-data="Components.tab(0)" aria-controls="tabs-1-panel-3" role="tab" x-init="init()"
                    @click="onClick" @keydown="onKeydown" @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" :tabindex="selected ? 0 : -1"
                    :aria-selected="selected ? 'true' : 'false'" type="button" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Back view</span>
                <span class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                    <img src="#" alt="" class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center">
                </span>
                <span class="ring-transparent pointer-events-none absolute inset-0 rounded-md ring-2 ring-offset-2"
                      aria-hidden="true" x-state:on="Selected" x-state:off="Not Selected"
                      :class="{ 'ring-indigo-500': selected, 'ring-transparent': !(selected) }"></span>
            </button>
            <button id="tabs-1-tab-4"
                    class="relative flex h-24 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-white text-sm font-medium uppercase text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:ring-offset-4"
                    x-data="Components.tab(0)" aria-controls="tabs-1-panel-4" role="tab" x-init="init()"
                    @click="onClick" @keydown="onKeydown" @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" :tabindex="selected ? 0 : -1"
                    :aria-selected="selected ? 'true' : 'false'" type="button" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Back angle open view</span>
                <span class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                    <img src="#" alt="" class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center">
                </span>
                <span class="ring-transparent pointer-events-none absolute inset-0 rounded-md ring-2 ring-offset-2"
                      aria-hidden="true" x-state:on="Selected" x-state:off="Not Selected"
                      :class="{ 'ring-indigo-500': selected, 'ring-transparent': !(selected) }"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1 w-full">
        <div id="tabs-1-panel-1" x-description="Tab panel, show/hide based on tab state."
             x-data="Components.tabPanel(0)" aria-labelledby="tabs-1-tab-1" x-init="init()" x-show="selected"
             @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0">
            <img src="#" alt="Angled front view with bag zipped and handles upright."
                 class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center sm:rounded-lg">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-1-panel-2" x-description="Tab panel, show/hide based on tab state."
             x-data="Components.tabPanel(0)" aria-labelledby="tabs-1-tab-2" x-init="init()" x-show="selected"
             @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
            <img src="#" alt="Front view with bag zipped and handles upright."
                 class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center sm:rounded-lg">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-1-panel-3" x-description="Tab panel, show/hide based on tab state."
             x-data="Components.tabPanel(0)" aria-labelledby="tabs-1-tab-3" x-init="init()" x-show="selected"
             @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
            <img src="#" alt="Back view with bag zipped and straps hanging down."
                 class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center sm:rounded-lg">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-1-panel-4" x-description="Tab panel, show/hide based on tab state."
             x-data="Components.tabPanel(0)" aria-labelledby="tabs-1-tab-4" x-init="init()" x-show="selected"
             @tab-select.window="onTabSelect" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
            <img src="#" alt="Back angled view with bag open and handles to the side."
                 class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center sm:rounded-lg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


You can fix the undefined function errors by copying the JavaScript component from tailwindui.com.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
